# Maximum theorem with linear constraints. On parametric continuity of in optimization

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, continuity

Given
\begin{align}
 s(\theta)= &\text{arg min}( g( \boldsymbol{x}) ) \\
 \text{subject to }&  \boldsymbol{A}(\theta)  \boldsymbol{x} =  \boldsymbol{b}(\theta)  \\
 &c_1 \le x_i \le c_2  , i \in \{1,2,\cdots, n\}
\end{align}.

where $ \theta\in \Theta$ , $  \boldsymbol{A}  \in \mathcal{R} ^{ m \times n}$ is full row rank, with  $m<n $, $ c_1 $ and $ c_2 $ are constants, both $  \boldsymbol{A}(\theta) $ and $  \boldsymbol{b}(\theta) $ is continuous and the problem is feasible for all $ \theta \in \Theta $.  Further $g(\boldsymbol{x})$ is continuous and strictly convex.

Does it follow from the [Maximum theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_theorem) that $s(\theta)$ is a continuous vector valued function?

---

The theorem is short and seems rather straight forward, however, I am in need a second opinion verifying that what I believe to hold is valid. (I still somewhat struggle with the concepts).

Below follows my simple draft

---

Let $\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $\theta \in \Theta \in \mathbb{R}^1$

Let the constraint set be denoted

$  C(\theta)=  \{  \boldsymbol{x}: \boldsymbol{A}(\theta)  \boldsymbol{x} =  \boldsymbol{b}(\theta)  , c_1 \le x_i \le c_2  , i \in \{1,2,\cdots, n\}   \} $

Now:

$ \theta \mapsto C(\theta) $ is compact (affine constraints) such that $ C(\theta) \neq \emptyset$ (assumption of feasibility)    $\forall \theta \in \Theta $. Therefore  $ C:\mathbb{R}^1 \rightrightarrows \mathbb{R}^n$ $ is a compact valued correspondence.

With $\boldsymbol{A}(\theta)$ full row rank, given continous parameters, $ C(\theta) $ is continous (implicit function theorem). Since also 
 $g( \boldsymbol{x})  $ is continuous,  by the maximum theorem (in this case we use the opposite version, i.e., minimum) , $ s(\theta) $ is continuous (i.e. both upper and lower hemicontinuous). Now due to strict convexity any solution is single-(vector) valued and $ s(\theta) $ is a continuous vector valued function.

Am I missing something?

---

Comment: what is $\Theta$ here?

Comment: It is the (topological) space of the scalar parameter $\theta$.  Could to my understanding be replaced with forexample $\Theta =\{ \theta : 
0 \le \theta \le k \} $. (i tried to write it similar as it is written in the theorem)